# d3, javascript and canvasing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js, geometry

So I have some javascript code with d3 that I need some assistance with. So in my main html file I have this canvas declared:

Then in another file I have these commands:

```
  var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")

  var data_var=get_data();

  var selection=canvas.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data_var)

  selection.enter().append("circle")
```

My issue is when canvas.selectAll("circle") is called, where is that "circle" coming from? I looked all over else where and the given canvas nor the input data has any type named "circle."

Comment: What's the resulting HTML generated after this code has run? Is the #canvas elem an svg elem?

Answer (score 1):

This is the tricky thing about d3.  Its API uses a declarative, instead of an imperative programming paradigm.  In creator Mike Bostock's words, it means you "tell d3 what you want, not what to do".  So what you are doing when you write d3.selectAll("circle") is tell d3, "OK, get ready, I'm about to append some svg circles here, so go ahead and select them".

Actually, it's a little more complicated than that.  If you already have some circles in your DOM, it will select as many as are in the `data` array, and then create circles corresponding to any remaining data elements when you call `enter().append("circle")`.  However, if the DOM has no circles on it (as is typically the case when you are creating a new chart), d3 selects circles *that don't yet exist*.  It is only when you call .data().enter().append("circle") does d3 put these circles selected on the DOM.

It's a tricky concept if you've never used a declarative interface before (I hadn't before d3).  Here are a few resources that helped me:

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data/  (see the "Please Make Your Selection" section)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! If I may bother you with one more question: I tried changing "circle" to "rect" and it didn't work. Are there limits to what you can append?

Comment: No, "rect" should work just fine, since it's one of the SVG objects available in d3.  You just have to make sure to change it under the `selectAll()` method and the `append()` method.  If you're still having problems, then please submit another question (and please don't forget to select an answer for this question).